# Refer to Array Index by Value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an the following data in SwiftUI.

```
struct Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var muscleGroup: [MuscleGroup]
    var equipment: [Equipment]
}

let exercises = [
    Exercise(name: "Ab Wheel", muscleGroup: [muscleGroups[0], muscleGroups[1]], equipment: [equipments[0], equipments[2]])
]
```

I want to refer to the muscleGroup and equipment values by name rather than index as that is easier for me. I have found solutions, however they only return the first value, rather than all values.

How can I refer to the index by value where it also returns all index items rather than only the first?

The solution I found was through a helper function, but this only returns the first value:

```
func getEquipment(names: [String]) -> [Equipment] {
    return equipments.filter { equipment in
        names.contains(equipment.name)
    }
}
```

When I implement that solution as such:

```
let exercises = [
    Exercise(name: "Ab Wheel", muscleGroup: [muscleGroups[0], muscleGroups[1]], equipment: getEquipment(names: ["Barbell", "Dumbbell"]))
]
```

I get the following result. I want both Barbell and Dumbell to appear:

[image: Result from solution that's been tried.]

Comment: What do you mean by "refer to" here? It's hard to understand how you want to use your data and why you are even using code like `muscleGroup: [muscleGroups[0], muscleGroups[1]]`

Comment: Your `getEquipment` is correct. It should return all matching values. You should show an example where this does not work as expected, along with what you expect it to do.

Comment: @vadian could you elaborate? I don't know what you mean by custom subscripts.

Comment: In `Exercise` you could  implement custom subscripts for `MuscleGroup` and `Equipment` for example to subscript by enum rather than by index. Custom subscripts are described [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/custom-subscripts/).

Comment: Edit your question to show what you expect that to do and what it actually does. Do not attempt to give large amounts of information in a comment. It's unreadable.

Comment: @RobNapier done! Does this make it more clear?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want it to be a relational model. So an exercise can have one or more muscle groups and can have one or more pieces of equipment. I want to be able to display the exercise together with the muscle groups and equipment.

If you have suggestions for another way to do this, please do let me know as I don't know another solution.

Comment: Use another ForEach

Comment: @loremipsum This only returns Barbell multiple times.

Comment: You haven't shown how you initialize `equipments`.  I somewhat suspect that it's missing `Dumbbell`. Perhaps you've spelled it slightly differently (capitalization matters here).

Comment: That is what is there then, that is what you have loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't completely clear what you are trying to do. I gather you want to have a type that is easy to read and lets you list values.

I suggest enums:

```
enum MuscleGroup {
    case lats
    case glutes
    case abs
    case pecs
}
```

If you need to  treat it as an integer so you can use it to index into arrays, make its base type Int:

```
enum MuscleGroup: Int {
    case lats
    case glutes
    case abs
    case pecs
}
```

You can then get a string description of any given MuscleGroup as well as a zero-based integer value using `rawValue`:

```
let aMuscleGroup = MuscleGroup.lats
print(String("aMuscleGroup = '\(String(describing: aMuscleGroup))'"))
print ("aMuscleGroup int value = \(aMuscleGroup.rawValue)")
```

That will log

```
aMuscleGroup = 'lats'
aMuscleGroup int value = 0
```

And you can use the rawValue to index into arrays. Say you have an array of exercises indexed by the muscle groups they work:

```
let latExercises = exercises[MuscleGroup.lats.rawValue]
```

Or your Exercise type:

```
struct Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var muscleGroup: [MuscleGroup]
    var equipment: [Equipment]
}

let exercises = [
    Exercise(name: "Ab Wheel", muscleGroup: [.lats, .pecs], equipment: [equipments[0], equipments[2]])
]
```

(And it would make sense to use enums for your `equipment` type as well. I leave that as an exercise for you.)

Comment: Is that what you were trying to do?